# how does voting work between two Tree-Based classifiers that are combined using hard voting in scikit?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

For a classification task, I am using [sklearn VotingClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html) to ensemble Random Forest and Extra-Tree Classifier with parameter set to `voting='hard'`. I don't understand how it works correctly since both Tree-Based models already give final prediction using voting technique. How can they work in combination using hard voting? Also if there is a tie between two models?
Can anyone explain this with example?

Comment: When you read the sklearn documentation (link please?), what does it tell you? And when you write code to test this out, what does it teach you? Else, this is [not an on-topic question for SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you can't expect people to do your work for you. If the sklearn doc is missing or inadequate, file a docbug on sklearn.

Comment: May be my question is not interpreting what i meant to say.There is nothing wrong in sklearn end.I have just an issue of understanding inner working of hard voting with two classifier especially tree-based.

Comment: As i have learn about different classifiers working, in case of soft voting it will check the probability of each class. In hard voting case it will take the majority votes for a class. But if i ensemble Random Forest (RF)and Extra-Tree (ET) they both inner working is like they give final prediction by counting voting from a number of decision trees. I am just wondering how it will work in combination.I am asking if someone teach me with example like there is 4 classes, RF and ET. both have decision tree in it and the votes are count in combination for a particular class?

Comment: Yes, I have read documentation of sklearn, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html, as well as different blogs, site search , research papers but still my point is about two algorithm combining. There is lot of links to sites i can share as em new learner and getting hard to find my answers correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can look that up from the source code of the voting classifier.
For short, it doesn't make much sense to use two classifiers with hard-voting. Rather use soft-voting.

The reason is, that in hard voting modus, the sklearn `VotingClassifier` votes for the mayority vote and with two it only gets interesting if there is a tie. In case there are as many zeros as there are ones in a binary classification, the hard voting classifier will vote for 0.

You can simply test that by looking at the code, that it executed:

First set up the data for the experiment:

```
import numpy as np
# create a random int array with values 0 and 1
# with 20 rows (20 predictions) of 10 voters (10 columns)
a = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(20,10))

# then produce some tie-lines with different combinations
a[0,:] = [0]*5 + [1]*5  # the first 5 predict 0 the next 5 predict 1
a[1,:] = [1]*5 + [0]*5  # vice versa
a[2,:] = [0,1]*5 # the first predicts 0 then 1 follows 0 and 0 follows 1
a[3,:] = [1,0]*5 # the same, just starting with 1

# if you want to check, how many ones you have, do:
a.sum(axis=1)
```

Now see, what the voter code does with this. The voter code for hard voting is (the code below simulates the case, where you have equally weighted classiifiers `weights=[1]*10`):

```
np.apply_along_axis(
                lambda x: np.argmax(
                    np.bincount(x, weights=[1.0]*10)),
                axis=1, arr=a)
```

The result is:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
```

You see, that for the first four entries (the ties we manually introduced), the result is 0. So in case of a tie, the voting classifier will always choose 0 (if you choose the same weight for each of the classifiers). Note, that the weights are not only used to resolve ties, so you could have a classifier which has the double weight of another classifier, so you might even get a tie with 3 classifiers this way. But whenever the sum of prediction*weight for all 0-predicting classifiers is equal to the sumf of prediciton*weight for all 1-predicting classifiers, the voting classifier will predict 0 rather than 1.

Here is the relevant code:
[Sklearn Voting code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/ensemble/_voting.py#L113) and [Description of numpy.argmax](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)